# Error occured processing XML 'Could not initialize class org.springframework.security.config.http.MatcherType'

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, primavera

I'm working with Spring security and Hibernate, but I am getting the following problem in the xml file `spring-security.xml`

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error occured processing XML

```
Could not initialize class org.springframework.security.config.http.MatcherType'. See Error Log for more details    spring-security.xml /testholding/WebContent/WEB-INF line 9  Spring Beans Problem
```

The problem is the HTTP /HTTP of `spring-security.xml`

I need help please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Post your code, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you please post the content of your `spring-security.xml` as well as the dependencies you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The message `Could not initialize class SomeClass` means that the JVM has already tried and failed to statically initialize the class `SomeClass`.  If you restart your web application container and make another attempt to reproduce the error, you may get a different message the first time.

Static initialization of a class consists of running any `static { }` blocks and assigning values given to any `static` fields.  In the case of the [MatcherType](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/3.1.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/config/http/MatcherType.java) class mentioned in your error message, the static initialization is as follows:

```
private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MatcherType.class);

private static final String ATT_MATCHER_TYPE = "request-matcher";
private static final String ATT_PATH_TYPE = "path-type";
```

The two string constants won't be a problem.  However, the first one is where I suspect the problem to be.  The method `LogFactory.getLog` is in Apache Commons Logging.

My bet is therefore that your web application is missing the commons-logging jar.  Try adding that and seeing if it makes a difference.